# How to have total control over an EKS ALB generated address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an ALB ingress deployed with the following annotation.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: testing-lb-name
```

However, the generated address of the load balancer is still having a random suffix after `testing-lb-name`.

I know we can use `nlb` instead with serviceType set to `LoadBalancer`, but I would lost the benefit of using a L7 load balancer that way.

Is there any way to enforce the address of an EKS ALB generated address, or attach a staticIP (e.g.  Elastic IP) to it?

By the way I'm deploying it in a local helm chart, so I hope the "address control" can be encapsulated in the chart (which I hope in the ingress resources annotation).

Comment: You can install [ExternalDNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) and use it to automatically create a CNAME for the load balancer. You can also assign a static IP to an NLB by using the service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations annotation, see https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/service/annotations/#traffic-routing.